# Is there a way to pass the message from the back end to front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend

I'm building a web app using react Java Script(front end) and Java Script for the back end and I've come across a problem, in the login I have it check the password to see if its right but it won't let me in if it's right or wrong... what am I doing wrong?, here is my back end code...

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
const { userName, password = req.body.password, hashPass } = req.query;

connection.query(
SELECT_USER_QUERY + ` WHERE userName= ? `,
[userName],
function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  else {
    if (results.length > 0) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, hashPass, function (err, result) {
        if (result) {
          return res.send({ message: 'Login Successful' });
        } else {
          return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid Password' });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid userName' });
    }
  }
}
);
});
```

and here is my front end code...

```
handleLogIn = async () => {
const { userName, password } = this.state.user;
const { users } = this.state;

await postFetch(`/users/login`, {
  userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
  password: password,
  hashPass: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password,
})
  .then(result => {
    //handle wrong password
    if (!result.success) {
      console.log(result.errors);
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        id: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id,
        firstName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName)
          .firstName,
        lastName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).lastName,
        userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
        password: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password,
        email: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).email,
      },
    });
    this.getPreference(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id);
    this.getReadings(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

do I pass the message from the back end to the front end and if so, how?

Comment: You don’t want the server to send some data, you just need to respond accordingly to the input. You have all you need debug the code you have.

Comment: Disregarding several other issues, `if (!result.success)` will always happen, since what you're sending back has no `.success` property, just a `.message` property.

Comment: so would I put something like if(result.message === 'Login Successful), and what other issues are their?

Comment: it worked for login successful but if i put an invalid user Name in it will crash, how do I tell it in react java Script to go to the register page?, I'm sorry i'm new at internet programming

Comment: if i put an invalid user Name in it will crash, how do I tell it in react java Script to go to the register page without it crashing?